# libg2o installation problem on ROS Hydro Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have complied RGBDSLAM v2's prerequisite to install ROS Hydro according to [Installing ROS Hydro on Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi) and put felixendres-rgbdslam_v2-7450b20 in catkin_ws/src.

When i run

```
rosdep install  --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy
```

i got

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: 
rgbdslam: No definition of [libg2o] for OS [debian]
```

then i run

```
roslocate info libg2o
```

I got

```
Using ROS_DISTRO: hydro WARNING: Package "libg2o" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).  
Not found via rosdistro - falling back to information provided by rosdoc. 
Missing VCS control information for package libg2o, requires vcs[] and vcs_uri[]
```

Can anyone helps with this problem?
I am trying to get RGBDSLAM running on Raspberrypi B+Wheezy(2014-12-24) with kinect.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200811/libg2o-installation-problem-on-ros-hydro-raspbian-wheezy/) by [enyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20668/enyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages are available on raspbian.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0